# 403 forbidden: CSRF Token failed while calling Gateway service from Fiori App using tomcat server

Tags: sapui5, netweaver

I have created the Fiori app(version 1.28) in web ide and imported into eclipse.
In component.js config, I have mentioned the complete odata service URL without proxy and opening the application in chrome with argument --disable web security.

I Just did some Odata model binding to items aggregation of table in my xml view.

And yes, I am using OData V2 model(auto generated code in models.js), handling of csrf token is by default true.

I can see the calls are fired one to fetch the CSRF token and the other to GET the data in a batch(POST request).
But still, I am facing issue that 403 Forbidden. Not able to understand why this is happening. Please find the attached.[CSRF Token Fetch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITSdw.jpg) and [CSRF Token Failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhymC.jpg)

Kindly suggest If I have to do any changes either in my UI5 code or in OData service implementation or Gateway configurations.

**Extract from Models.js**

```
createODataModel: function(oOptions) {
    var aUrlParametersForEveryRequest, oConfig, sUrl;
    oOptions = oOptions || {};
    if (!oOptions.url) {
        jQuery.sap.log.error("<ErrorText>");
        return null;
    }
    oConfig = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oOptions.config);
    aUrlParametersForEveryRequest = oOptions.urlParametersForEveryRequest || [];
    oConfig.metadataUrlParams = oConfig.metadataUrlParams || {};
    sUrl = extendMetadataUrlParameters(aUrlParametersForEveryRequest, oConfig.metadataUrlParams, oOptions.url);
    return new ODataModel(sUrl, oConfig);
}
```

**Extract from Component.js**

```
"config": {
    "i18nBundle": "ZMM_PMTOT.i18n.i18n",
    "serviceUrl": "https://<host>:<port>/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMM_PMTOT/",
},
init: function() {
    var mConfig = this.getMetadata().getConfig();
    var oModel = models.createODataModel({
        urlParametersForEveryRequest: ["sap-server", "sap-client", "sap-language"],
        url: this.getMetadata().getConfig().serviceUrl,
        config: {
            metadataUrlParams: {
                "sap-documentation": "heading"
            }
        }
    });
    this.setModel(oModel);
    this._createMetadataPromise(oModel);
}
```

Thanks in Advance..!!

With Best Regards,
Phaneendra

Comment: maybe you can check transaction /iwfnd/error_log and debug the call, maybe it provides a hint why you it is forbidden. does the request arrive at the backend? otherwise provide some code, only the requests do not help at this point.

Comment: Hi @zyrex,
I have checked the gateway error log. But nothing was maintained over there. So, I assume that backend call itself is not going for 'POST'. For 'GET', yes, breakpoint was triggered.

Please check the below code in models.js generated by webide.

Comment: Models.js

createODataModel: function(oOptions) {
var aUrlParametersForEveryRequest,oConfig,sUrl;
oOptions = oOptions || {};
if (!oOptions.url) {
jQuery.sap.log.error("<ErrorText>");
return null;}
oConfig = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oOptions.config);   aUrlParametersForEveryRequest = oOptions.urlParametersForEveryRequest || [];
oConfig.metadataUrlParams = oConfig.metadataUrlParams || {};
sUrl = extendMetadataUrlParameters(aUrlParametersForEveryRequest, oConfig.metadataUrlParams, oOptions.url);
return new ODataModel(sUrl, oConfig);},

Comment: Component.js
___________


   "config": {
    "i18nBundle": "ZMM_PMTOT.i18n.i18n",
    "serviceUrl": "https://<host>:<port>/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZMM_PMTOT/",
   },
auto genrated code by web ide:
_______________________
 init: function() {
var mConfig = this.getMetadata().getConfig();
var oModel = models.createODataModel({
urlParametersForEveryRequest: [
"sap-server",
"sap-client",
"sap-language"
],
url: this.getMetadata().getConfig().serviceUrl,
config: {
metadataUrlParams: {
"sap-documentation": "heading"
}
}
});
this.setModel(oModel);
this._createMetadataPromise(oModel);

Comment: I added your comments to your question for better readability